# Recursive function doesn't return an extra zero

Tags: python, recursion

I am new to programming and learning python. I came across recursion and getting my head around this code :
'''

```
def rec_count(n):
    print(n)
    #Base case
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    rec_count(n-1) # a recursive call    
    print(n)
```

'''

On calling 'rec_count(2)', I get below output
2
1
0
1
2

I was expecting 2-1-0-0-1-2 as the output. Because, when n becomes 0, the function will first print 0 and then again return 0 since n==0 condition is satisfied. But why doesn't it print the 0 twice ?

Comment: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20rec_count%28n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28n%29%0A%20%20%20%20%23Base%20case%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%0A%20%20%20%20rec_count%28n-1%29%20%23%20a%20recursive%20call%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20print%28n%29%0A%0Arec_count%282%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: When n==0, the second print can never be executed, as the function returns before.

Comment: Why return anything? You ignore the return value of the recursive call. `print` and `return` are not the same thing.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille - I got that part. I was mistaken in assuming return 0 will also print a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write as following

```
def rec_count(n):
    print(n)
    if n == 0:
        print(n)
        return 0
    rec_count(n-1)
    print(n)
```

Call:

```
rec_count(2)
```

Output:

```
2
1
0
0
1
2
```